# Iterrows a rolling sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a **pandas** dataframe

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
```

where each row corresponds to one case, and each column corresponds to one month. I want to perform a rolling sum over each 12 month period. Seems simple enough, but I'm getting stuck with

```
result = [x for x.rolling_sum(12) in df.iterrows()]
result = [x for x.rolling_sum(12) in df.T.iteritems()]
```

SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

```
a = []
for x in df.iterrows():
    s = x.rolling_sum(12)
    a.append(s)
```

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rolling_sum'

Comment: Where is `rolling_sum` defined?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire rolling_sum is a methods of `pandas.Series`. I will edit the code to include an explicit reference to it.

Comment: You should write `for i,x in df.iterrows():` to make x a series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think perhaps what you are looking for is

```
pd.rolling_sum(df, 12, axis=1)
```

In which case, no list comprehension is necessary. The `axis=1` parameter causes Pandas to compute a rolling sum over *rows* of `df`.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ncols, nrows = 13, 2
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(ncols*nrows).reshape(nrows, ncols))
print(df)
#    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
# 0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
# 1  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25

print(pd.rolling_sum(df, 12, axis=1))
```

prints

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   66   78
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  222  234
```

---

Regarding your list comprehension:

You've got the parts of the list comprehension in the wrong order. Try:

```
result = [expression for x in df.iterrows()]
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more about list comprehensions.

The basic form of a list comprehension is

```
[expression for variable in sequence]
```

And the resultant list is equivalent to `result` after Python executes:

```
result = []
for variable in sequence:
    result.append(expression)
```

See [this link](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) for full syntax for list comprehensions.

Comment: That solves the first problem, next problem is that iterrows() yields tuples and iteritems() yields key-value pairs, neither has a `rolling_sum` method.

Comment: Thanks. For `[x.rolling_sum(12) for x in df.iterrows()]` I get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rolling_sum'`